# remove line break between form label and input cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

the form helper in cakephp generates form elements like this usually:

```
<div class="input text">
  <label for="Firstname">Firstname</label>
  <input type="text" id="Firstname" value="" class="test" name="Firstname"/>
</div>
```

but is it possible to remove the line break that is between the `<label>` and the `<input>` to have something like this:

```
<div class="input text">
  <label for="Firstname">Firstname</label>    <input type="text" id="Firstname" value="" class="test" name="Firstname"/>
</div>
```

Any idea please?

Thank you

Comment: What's wrong with the line break? Does it do something that is shouldn't?

Comment: Are you sure it creates line breaks? In my app looking at page source I have exactly this: `<div class="input text"><label for="name">Name</label><input name="data[name]" type="text" id="name"/></div>` Theres no whitespace between tags.

Comment: yes it does put a line break, I don't know why

Answer (score 7):

The "line break" is not in the HTML, rather it is in the default CakePHP CSS. In order to solve this, I add the following CSS rules in the CakePHP apps that I bake:

```
label {
    display: inline;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
input, textarea {
    width: 76%;
    clear: none;
}
form div.submit {
    clear: none;
    display: inline;
}
```

This basically inlines both the label and the input, and sets widths for them appropriately (you may want to change the numbers for your app, depending on the length.)

Let me know if this works. You can add these lines to the bottom of APP/webroot/css/cake.generic.css or add a new CSS file if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with @srs2012 's answer, but there is a way  to format the output of the Form Helper.

The FormHelper::input() action also accepts a 'format' key in it's second parameter.
This key is a format template for element order. The default input format order is:

```
array('before', 'label', 'between', 'input', 'after', 'error')
```

Any element that is not in the array, will not be in the output. So if you modify this and remove the 'between' key it might just work.

As an example:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Model.name', array('format' => array('before', 'label', 'input', 'after', 'error')));
```

I have actually had to use this setting only once in a project. [Here it is](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/form-helper#method-FormHelperinput) in the CakePHP 1.3 API.
Play around with it a bit a see what you can come up with.